# Only get a searched Id data in datagridview,renaming data should not be visible

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = customer.Properties.Settings.Default.Db;
                OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT tbl_Customer.CustomerID,tbl_Customer_Trans.Date,tbl_Customer_Trans.DailyEntry,tbl_Customer_Trans.DailyInt, tbl_Customer_Trans.Fine  
    FROM tbl_Customer ,tbl_Customer_Trans  
    WHERE  tbl_Customer.CustomerID = tbl_Customer_Trans.CustomerID;", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["CustomerID"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["Date"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["DailyEntry"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["DailyInt"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["Fine"].ToString();
                    int a = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value);
                    int b = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value);
                    int c = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value);
                    int d = a + b + c ;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = d;
                }
```

When user enters Id in text Box only the entered ID data should be visible,if user enters ID = 1, then on id 1 values which are saved in table should be visible.with my code all the values which are present in table are visible